# Checkbox field in OrderList

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to create OrderList with Primefaces. 
This list would make possible changing order of items and allow setting some boolean with a checkbox. Changing the order is fine.

The problem is that every checkbox gets the same id. 
When I am clicking on one of them, then the value of all of them change.
Here is my snippet:

```
<p:orderList id="OrderList" value="#{editBean.visibleitem}" var="item" 
                 itemValue="#{item}" controlsLocation="left" responsive="true" 
                 converter="converter">

                    <f:facet name="caption">
                            <div>
                                    <div style="float: left">label</div>
                                    <div style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15px">checkbox</div>
                            </div>
                    </f:facet>

                <p:column style="width:80%">
                    <h:outputText value="item" styleClass="bst-text"/>
                </p:column>

               <p:column style="width:20%; text-align: center">               
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id_item" 
                valueChangeListener="editBean" 
                value="#{item.object.booleanObj}">
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
               </p:column> 
</p:orderList>
```

I will be happy if you could help me.
Greetings :)

Comment: What is your primefaces version? Tried latest One? Tried a plain JSF input text instead to see if that failed to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an open enhancement request currently in PrimeFaces 6.2 found here:

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3781

I will see if we can get it implemented before the 7.0 release.

Comment: I would not call it a bug... More of an enhancement like stated in the issue. Imo this component was never meant to be used as an input. Next requests will be filtering, sorting, paging etc. All can be done with the datatable and with some small html and javascript in there, you can get the reordering working too.

Comment: You are right its a UIInput component unlike DataGrid and Datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your responses. I decided to redesign my UI and now I don't display checkboxes in OrderList Component.